# excel vba - msgbox abort/retry/ignore

Tags: vba, excel

I am validating input in an Excel worksheet. When the user enters invalid data a `MsgBox` is shown, giving the option to Abort/Retry/Ignore.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If IsNumeric(Range("i17")) Then
        If [I17] < 0 Then
            result = MsgBox("Critical Error Encountered", vbAbortRetryIgnore + vbCritical, "Error Encountered")
            If result = 3 Then
                ActiveCell.Value = Empty            
            End If
        End If
    End If
End sub
```

Since I have written this code in `SelectionChange` when I click enter then only it show the message box and since I'm writing `Active.Cell = Empty` it is deleting the next cell, but I mean it to clear the cell which contains invalid data.

Comment: So which is "the cell which contains invalid data"? Is it `I17`? Then why you don't clear `I17`? Or is it the cell which is changed *before* `Worksheet_SelectionChange`? Then use the event `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`. There the `Target` contains this cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `SelectionChange` event, the `Target` range is the cell just selected and not the cell which has just been changed. If you use the `Change` event of the worksheet, then `Target` refers to the cell that has been changed. So, assuming that cell I17 is some kind of subtotal/validation cell and not the cell into which the user enters data, try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If IsNumeric(Range("i17")) Then
        If [I17] < 0 Then
            result = MsgBox("Critical Error Encountered", vbAbortRetryIgnore + vbCritical, "Error Encountered")
            If result = 3 Then
                Target.Value = Empty
                Target.Select
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This code will clear the cell just changed and change the selection back to that cell if the user selects the Abort button in the message.